# Why am I getting the More space between child views in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am facing the Problem of getting the More Space between the Child Views in LinearLayout in the `ldpi`,`mdpi` & `hdpi` density devices. But for the remaining its work fine.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_file_item"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_file_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text= "@string/text_file_name"
                android:textColor="@color/title_bar_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_rename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/txt_rename"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_status_color_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here I am trying to set the margin for the second Child its around "`10dp`" when I changed to "`5dp`" its Working fine.But I need "`10dp`" as space for second Child. I encountered the Problem with First Child there I am mentioned the Weight for my requirement. When I remove its Working fine. Can any one help me out? please.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scst1.jpg) for Large Text.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smoze.jpg) for samller Text.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.  read this .

Comment: Are you telling that Hard-code the Margin value based on the Density?

Comment: Can you add some sample image for what you need try to do look like?

Comment: I place them in my question. I didn't get any option to upload the images so edited my question with images.

Comment: Can you tell exactly where are you facing the problem? You are getting space because of margin in your child views.

Comment: for ldpi, mdpi & hdpi devices if having the small Textview Name for First child like " Image " then it occurs more gap between First and second child. On the screen it displaying like first child occupies half of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i could  understand your question properly.

So this issue can solve by using layout weight in  Linear layout. By using it you will get proper space for each view and it will adjust automatically with elements inside it.
First you have to assign Weight sum property in parent view - which shows in how many parts you want to divide your child views, and in child views use Layout_weight - Which describe about space you want to assign that particular view,

as shown in below code  it can help you...

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:weightSum="4">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_mail" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="GbrjjZnqw59jrnGKHq9wtFcZRuj7py7jxu8zeuZNsCGbrjjZnqw59jrnGKHq9wtFcZRuj7py7jxuyz" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Rename"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Now You can adjust margin, padding as per your requirement in above code.

Hope This may will help you!!

Thanks!